# Memory issue in parallel Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a Python script like this:

```
from modules import functions
a=1
parameters = par_vals
for i in range(large_number):
    #do lots of stuff dependent on a, plot stuff, save plots as png
```

When I run this for a value of "a" it takes half an hour, and uses only 1 core of my 6 core machine.

I want to run this code for 100 different values of "a"

The question is: How can I parallelize this so I use all cores and try all values of "a"?

my first approach following an online suggestion was:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def repeat(a):
    from modules import functions
    parameters = par_vals
    for i in range(large_number):
        #do lots of stuff dependent on a, plot stuff, save plots as png

A=list_100_a #list of 100 different a values
Parallel(n_jobs=6,verbose=0)(delayed(repeat)(a) for a in A)
```

This successfully use all my cores in the computer but it was computing for all the 100 values of a at the same time. after 4 hours my 64GB RAM memory and 64GB swap memory would be saturated and the performance dropped drastically.
So I tried to manually cue the function doing it 6 times at a time inside a for loop. But the problem was that the memory would be consumed also.

I don't know where the problem is. I guess that somehow the program is keeping unnecessary memory.

What can I do so that I don't have this memory problem.

In summary:
When I run this function for a specific value of "a" everything is ok.
When I run this function in parallel for 6 values of "a" everything is ok.
When I sequencially run this function in parallel the memory gradually inscreases until the computer can no longer work.

---

UPDATE: I found a solution for the memory problem even though I don't understand why.

It appears that changing the backend of matplotlib to 'Agg' no longer produced the memory problem.

just add this before any import and you should be fine:

```
from matplotlib import use
use('Agg')
```

Comment: python 2.7.4 and ipython 1.0dev

Comment: Have you tried running this outside of IPython? I also suggest dumping `joblib` and directly using `multiprocessing`.

Comment: no, I will try that now. I wish I understood how to do this on multiprocessing. I am unable to find examples that suit my needs

Comment: @NunoCalaim Do you know what backend it was using before that?

Comment: Yes, by default it uses 'TkAgg', can this be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it with `multiprocessing`.  I'll use your `repeat` function to do the work for one value of `a`.

```
def repeat(a):
    from modules import functions
    parameters = par_vals
    for i in range(large_number):
        #do lots of stuff dependent on a, plot stuff, save plots as png
```

Then I'd use `multiprocessing.pool` like this:

```
import multiprocessing

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6)  # Create a pool with 6 workers.
A=list_100_a #list of 100 different a values

# Use the workers in the pool to call repeat on each value of a in A.  We
# throw away the result of calling map, since it looks like the point of calling
# repeat(a) is for the side effects (files created, etc).
pool.map(repeat, A) 

# Close the pool so no more jobs can be submitted to it, then wait for 
# all workers to exit.
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

If you wanted the result of calling repeat, you could just do `result = pool.map(repeat, A)`.

I don't think you'll run into any issues, but it's also useful to read the [programming guidelines](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) for using `multiprocessing`.

Comment: It worked but with the same problem of memory. I will accept your answer as it taught e how to use multiprocessing for doing exactly what I want. The memory problem however was solved by changing a backend, see my edited question for details